# Stop Jackson truncating decimal values for integral numbers

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson to map JSON to an object with a `long` field. I am using Jackson with Jersey to consume a JSON request. Let's say the parameter in my controller method is an object Foo.

```
public class Foo {

    @Digits(integer = 12, fraction = 0)
    private long id;

    public long getId() {return id;}

    public void setId(long id) {this.id = id;}
}
```

When I give a decimal value instead of an integral number in my JSON input, I want to show an error, so I am using `javax.Validation` annotations.

However, due to the use of `long`, the digits after the decimal get truncated and there are no errors, rather than throwing an error. For example, `1.23` gets truncated to `1`.

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: I am not seeing any Long being used here, only primitives. Can you be more specific with an example?

Comment: Do you mean "decimal input" as in the argument for the function? That's unrelated to Jackson; it's Java that you wanna look at.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I assume OP wants an error if JSON contains floating-point representation, like "1.25". By default Jackson tries its best to map things, which means truncation of some sorts.